# pip error ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, pip

Pip install pymem
Collecting pymem
Using cached

```
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/f5/f26541dc8a8b54cccecacc188ed4d7b8bf6f38c50bd04aaebc101213f598/Pymem-1.1.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-of2ias6a\\pymem\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-of2ias6a\\pymem\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-of2ias6a\pymem\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-of2ias6a\pymem\setup.py", line 8, in <module>
        with open(ROOT / 'requirements-doc.txt', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-of2ias6a\\pymem\\requirements-doc.txt'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

python  переустанавливал не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновите ***pip***
Команда для этого:
python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: P.S Если помогло то поставте галочку на ответе

Comment: И да еще если вдруг не помогла эта загуглите как обновить pip

Answer (score 0):

Устанавливайте в таком порядке. Это сработает

```
apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev
pip install mysqlclient
```